# Unix command to find unique Account ids in a unix file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

My unix file has the below content. How do i find the unique AccountIds?

i.e output of below should be: 1, 2

```
2015-03-06 11:27:13 print log:71 - AcountId: 1  logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:13 print log:71 - AcountId: 2  logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:13 print log:71 - AcountId: 1  logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:13 print log:71 - AcountId: 1  logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:13 print log:71 - AcountId: 1  logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:26 print log:71 - AcountId: 1 logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:26 print log:71 - AcountId: 1 logoutput date 2015-03-06
2015-03-06 11:27:26 print log:71 - AcountId: 1 logoutput date 2015-03-06
```

Comment: `cut -f 7 file.txt | sort -u`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -oP 'AcountId: \K\d+' file | sort -u
```

That relies on GNU grep's pcre implementation: it looks for "AcountId: ", then forgets about it, then looks for digits, which it outputs due to the `-o` flag. Pass through `sort -u` just to find the distinct ids